# How can I get a delete confirm in asp:GridView

Tags: asp.net

How do I pop up a delete confirm for a delete button in an asp:GridView?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have a delete button for each row in a GridView, here is what I think is the best (and definitely easiest) way to have it put up an alert asking for confirmation. Here is the full aspx code (there is no code-behind needed):

```
<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
  <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteButton" runat="server"
      CausesValidation="False"
      CommandName="Delete"
      OnClientClick='<%# Eval("Title", "return confirm(\"Delete the datasource {0}?\");") %>'
      Text="delete" />
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

A couple of notes:

1. The CommandName must be Delete - that is what maps this to the
   GridView delete functionality.
2. Title is the data column name of the
   title of that row. What you use here will depend on the
   column/property names of your data.
3. Same for the word datasource -
   that is what we have rows of. You need to replace with what your
   data is called.
4. I think <%$ resource_name %> should work for the
   text - but have not done that yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GridView, you are on a wrong track. Pros don't use it. They almost exclusively use ListView. So don't bother with it. Most books do not teach industrial best practices.

Comment: @David Thielen: Using javascript to confirm a delete as pointed out below is good but not reliable, because js is on the client browser and out of your control. Javascript could be disabled on the client browser for security clearence, so the confirm window will not show. Best way to confirm a delete is to put a ListView in a MultiView and catch the item-deleting event in the ListView and switch to another view in the MultiView to confirm the delete. Once a certain custom button is pressed, you manually delete the record from database.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the onlick attribute to the delete link dynamically, on RowDataBound of the grid view.

In the code below we have a 3 column table, so the columnIndex = 2. Also, there is only one auto gen button (delete), so the autoButtonIndex = 0. If we had an edit button, save buttons, this index would change.

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound

Dim columnIndex As Integer = 2
Dim autoButtonIndex as Integer = 0  

    Try
        If (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow) Then

            If (e.Row.RowState = DataControlRowState.Normal Or e.Row.RowState = DataControlRowState.Alternate) Then

                Dim lnkBtn As LinkButton = CType(e.Row.Cells(columnIndex).Controls(autoButtonIndex), LinkButton)
                lnkBtn.Attributes.Add("onclick", "if(!confirm('Are you sure to delete this row?'))return false;")

            End If

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

Don't forget to deal with your exception appropriately.